# ¿Cómo controlar la cantidad de valores agregados a la matriz?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function sorteio() {
    const btn = document.getElementById('btn')
    const numerosEscolhidos = document.getElementById('numerosEscolhidos')
    const numerosSorteados = document.getElementById('numerosSorteados')
    const valor = document.getElementById('valor').value
    let escolhidos = []

    if (escolhidos.length <= 5) {
        escolhidos.push(valor)
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < escolhidos.length; i++) {
        numerosEscolhidos.innerHTML += escolhidos[i]
    }
}
```

```html
<section>
        <input type="text" name="valor" id="valor" placeholder="Digite o valor: ">
        <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="sorteio()">Adicionar</button>
        <div id="numerosEscolhidos"></div>
        <div id="numerosSorteados"></div>
    </section>
```

Este código es para agregar un máximo de 6 valores a una matriz y representar la matriz en el navegador. ¿Cómo agregar un máximo de 6 valores en la matriz?

Answer (score 0):

## Solución

El truco está en usar `return`. Cuando usas `return`, invalidas el resto del código. Esto hace que el código se ejecute únicamente hasta el momento en el que se pone `return`. A menos de unos casos específicos.

```js
const escolhidos = [];

function sorteio() {
    const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    const numerosEscolhidos = document.getElementById('numerosEscolhidos');
    const numerosSorteados = document.getElementById('numerosSorteados');
    const valor = document.getElementById('valor').value;

    if (escolhidos.length > 5) return;
    
    escolhidos.push(valor)
    numerosEscolhidos.innerHTML += valor;
}

document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", sorteio);
```

```html
<section>
    <input type="text" name="valor" id="valor" placeholder="Digite o valor: ">
    <button type="button" id="btn">Adicionar</button>
    <div id="numerosEscolhidos"></div>
    <div id="numerosSorteados"></div>
</section>
```

El truco está aquí:

```js
if (escolhidos.length > 5) return;
```

En este caso, admitiremos 6 valores, porque le estamos poniendo la condición de que el código termine de ejecutarse siempre y cuando el número de elementos contenidos en el `Array` sea mayor que 5 o igual que 6.

---

### Consideraciones

- **El número de elementos se reiniciaba**: Cuando pones a escuchar a un evento, la función que le pusiste se ejecutará de nuevo cada vez que el evento suceda. En este caso, vuelves a definir la variable de `escolhidos`, lo que hacía que siempre haya un solo elemento, por lo que el `Array` siempre se reiniciaba y la condición nunca se cumplía.
- **Usaste `for`**: Como te dije, la variable del `Array` se definía de nuevo con cada clic, lo que hacía que nunca haya más de 1 elemento, en tu caso funcionaba porque el `Array` solo tenía un elemento, pero necesitamos definir la variable de fuera para que no se reinicie, en este caso, usar `for`, no aplica porque va a volver a iterar todos y cada uno de los elementos y volverlos a añadir. En este caso, por ejemplo, si el `Array` tuviese un elemento y le pones otro, aparecerán 4 elementos porque se iteran dos elementos, dos veces.
- **Separa la lógica de la estructura**: Es más legible usar [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) en vez de usar elementos con atributos `on`, esto generalmente dificulta la comprensión del código.

---

### Enlaces de interés y referencias

- [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`element.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
- [`Array.prototype.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)
- [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- [`element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)
- [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Comment: Obrigado @RodrigoRamirez